# Is there any polite equivalent to "genitals"?

Tags: word-choice

Albeit slightly conflicting, I was wondering if there's any more "polite", or better flowing word other than "genitals" in the context of:

> His genitals were cut off.

It would be prefered if the sentence was **not** reworded like:

> His groin was destroyed.

However, the above ^ is generally what I'm looking for in terms of tone, since it sounds, in a way, a bit less "rough". Would there be any better word than "genitals" given the context?

Comment: _Genitals_ seems quite a polite choice of word, considering the plethora of alternatives that comes to mind... Maybe you could say "removed" instead of the more descriptive "cut off"? Or you could consider the more medical _genitalia_.

Comment: Male attributes?

Comment: *private parts*

Comment: You could simply say he was physically emasculated.  That's the literal meaning of the word.  Of course, in the physical sense, it can't apply to women.

Comment: Both of the first two answers offered seem to ignore the severing of the penis, which commonly is left alone when a male is *castrated* or his *gonads* are removed.  See [a 1914 translation of a description of the more destructive act](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Hes.+Th.+173): “lopped off his own father’s members.”

Comment: Here's a buffet of words: member, nether regions, private parts, phallus, penis, John Thomas, manhood, todger, winkle, tool, ol' chap, willy, twig and berries, Johnson.

Comment: You haven't given any context for this, or reason why groin sounds rough to you.  It sounds like you just want people to check a thesaurus for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [word](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/castration) for this :

> **castration**
>
> - (Surgery) to remove the testes of; emasculate :
>
> > *The veterinarian castrated the two bulls.*

You can talk about *"his castration"* without being worried about being impolite. Nevertheless, this will remain a very sensitive subject.

Comment: Do you mean _sensitive_ instead of _sensible_?

Answer (score 0):

You could say that they removed his ***[gonads.](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gonads)***

> Primary reproductive organs: the ovaries and testes.

thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

*He lost his manhood* would be most likely understood to mean that his genitals were irreparably damaged of removed.

*He was emasculated*: meaning castrated, or having the testicles removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could have some fun with recent popular history.

> His genitals suffered the same fate as John Bobbitt's.

Comment: You know better than to post a comment as an answer, Paul. Clever comment anyway :-)